# Difficulties with setting up a difficult mySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a query to get data from a database, but I can't get it done.

I have the following table with dummy data:

```
id | date  

0  | 2011-11-25 20:12:32
1  | 2011-11-15 20:12:32
2  | 2011-11-05 20:12:32
3  | 2011-10-25 20:12:32
4  | 2011-10-15 20:12:32
5  | 2011-10-05 20:12:32
6  | 2010-10-25 20:12:32
7  | 2010-04-25 20:12:32
8  | 2009-07-25 20:12:32
```

---

I want to make a query that:

- Sorts the date by Year, then Month and then the Day
- Then it should count how many time of every month in these years there are.

If you don't get what I mean:
It should give a result something like this (using the dummy data from the table):

---

```
Year | Month | amount (of rows with that month in that year)

2011 | 11    | 3
2011 | 10    | 3
2010 | 4     | 2
2009 | 7     | 1
```

I have some knowledge of mySQL, but this is to much for me. :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: +1 For showing the the sample data and the desired output. I'm only missing the section showing what you tried so far...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT YEAR(`date`)  AS `year`, 
       MONTH(`date`) AS `month`, 
       COUNT(*)      AS amount 
FROM   `table` 
GROUP  BY YEAR(`date`), 
          MONTH(`date`) 
ORDER  BY `date` DESC
```

Comment: OMG! This code works. This code is so simple when I look at it. To bad I couldn't built it myself. Well, still got a lot to learn. xD Thank you so much, Jake

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT YEAR(date) AS Year, MONTH(date) AS Month, COUNT(*) as amount
FROM table
GROUP BY LEFT(date, 7)
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your query:

```
SELECT count(*) from t GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```